# How to load content when hosting on win forms?

Tags: c#, xna

I'm trying to host xna into windows form.
But when I use "Content.Load":

```
spriteFont = content.Load<SpriteFont>(@"Content\Fonts\smallFont");
```

it gives me an error:

> File not found.

I think this is because I have no "Content reference" in my win forms project.

My question is: How can I load content when hosting xna on win forms? Or how to add "content reference" into win forms project?

thanks!

Comment: Verify that the file actually exist in the relative location. Check if you also need to provide the extension, like "[...]\smallFont.abc"

Comment: @oleksii: The file extension is always `.xnb` and shouldn't be included in the path passed to `Load`.

Comment: @Vano: Take a look at [this answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6736081/3d-in-winforms/6741553#6741553), which explains how to get the content project reference.

Comment: @Andrew Russell: thank you for the link. It is good idea to use Windows Game Library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a good tutorial on how to use XNA in WinForms, plus load content.

[XNA WinForms](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/winforms_series_2)