# 3d (Direct3D) in WinForms - but .NET 2.0

Tags: .net-2.0, direct3d

Question is similar to:

[3D in WinForms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6736081/3d-in-winforms)

But - project is written in .NET 2.0 using c#.  Here is the screenshot, to avoid 1000 words:

[image: VideoPhill Player]

This is done with GDI+.  To be able to go further, I am thinking of using 3D rendering for waveform display.

Question: Does anyone have the idea of hosting ONE 3D viewport with full rendering into the .NET forms app?

Tips:
- I am somehow familiar with Ogre
- I won't convert whole project to WPF
- more tips as story develops...

Comment: You seem to be tipping answers towards [MOGRE](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/MOGRE)... why not come out and say so?

Comment: well, I have nothing against mogre, but I would like to know if it is possible (and someone can prove it) to box it inside the winforms control

Answer (score 2):

You can use XNA framework version v2.0 (v2.0 is for .NET 2.0).
[Start here](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/6471/34180.aspx#34180) for example.

Comment: I dug and dug and did't find that link.  I'll try to move in that direction, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For now, it seems that SlimDx could do the trick.  Would like to see something better suited, however...